# How can I save from knockoutjs json list data to asp.net mvc 3 controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

I Have this json data from knockoutjs

```
[{"Title":"test","Description":"tset","Price":"500.00","Status":"Reserved"}, 
 {"Title":"s","Description":"d","Price":"400","Status":"Reserved"}]
```

How can I save this to my controller in asp.net mvc 3?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could send it as an AJAX request:

```
var model = [{"Title":"test","Description":"tset","Price":"500.00","Status":"Reserved"}, {"Title":"s","Description":"d","Price":"400","Status":"Reserved"}];
$.ajax({
    url: '/somecontroller/someaction',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(model),
    success: function(result) {

    }
});
```

and then you would have a controller action that will receive this request:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(IEnumerable<MyViewModel> model)
{
    ...
}
```

where `MyViewModel` would of course reflect JSON structure:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```